# AngularJS: Join database tables and view them on the browser

Tags: angularjs, database, visual-studio, join, relational-database

I have three tables on my SQL LocalDB in Visual Studio (Student, Subject and Grades). Grades table relates to the other two using foreign keys. I need to join these tables and show the result as a table on my browser.
I know how to show just one table but can't figure this one out. What do I do?
Do I build a model on a SQL query ?

Comment: You need write a query for joining the tables. Use inner join in mysql

Comment: @Namal , I know how to write the query, but I need to show the query result on my browser, as a table using controllers and html views.

Comment: If you can give us the code that you already have then we can help you.

Comment: Did u get the reaults? Then you have to use 2 loops to dispaly the data

Comment: So to fetch the data of just one table, the controller would be

var app = angular.module("app", [])
.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/api/Students")
         .then(function (response) {
             $scope.students = response.data;})
})

but I don't want this, I want to join three tables and then use the controller to show the result. @Namal how do I use 2 loops? Can you guys give more details, I'm a beginner :P

Comment: Please show ur query for joining the tables.

Comment: SELECT Student.Name
    , Student.Surname
    , Student.Major
    , Subject.Name
 ,Grades.Grade
 
FROM Grades
INNER JOIN Student
    on Grades.StudentId = Student.Id
INNER JOIN Subject
    on Grades.SubjectId = Subject.Id

Comment: @Goldenowner wake up, I need you :P